# How do I get coupons in Paladins?

Tags: paladins

In the Activity Center there is a "Coupons" tab, they allow to buy skins with a reduced price. The only coupon I've seen at the moment is the one for Androxus Exalted Skin.

[image: paladins androxus coupon]

I've done some research ([reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Paladins/comments/6vkipw/how_do_you_get_coupons/), [official forum](http://forums.paladins.com/showthread.php?54538-What-are-Coupons) and [steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/444090/discussions/0/1471969431583383585/)) but found nothing that explains how to get these coupons. Are they random ? from a chest ? a quest ?

How can I get more coupons ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the coupon system in Paladins is similar to that in smite. The description of how to get coupons reads as so:

> [Coupons are only rewarded for things set up and flat (no automation), and Coupons have an internal cooldown so they won't happen back to back.](https://smite.gamepedia.com/Coupon_System)